# AWS AppSync GraphQL one to many relation connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, model, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am using AWS Appsync with dynamoDB and trying to create a connection between two schema **Course** and **Badges** in which once course can have multiple badges list. While badges list are static (don't change it frequently). I tried this but it doesn't worked.

[image]

```
type Badge @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private}]) {
  id: ID!
  Name: String
}

type Course @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private}]) {
  id: ID!
  badges: [Badge] @connection
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship) as for the documentation.
Please make sure that you don't read the legacy docs, as @connection directive is deprecated.

Hope it helps!